# Longsword combo activating jump slash

Tags: monster-hunter-world

I have done a few times but I cannot catch the pattern/trigger criteria of a particular Longsword combo.

By using R2+Triangle I will perform a stab, occasionally a follow up combo will occur where I will jump up and slash back down dealing multiple small damage, I find this move very useful but lack the ability to actively trigger it.

So far I only noticed a red glow during the stab which causes the jump slash but no hint of what triggers the glow. I have confirmed that having maxed Spirit does not guarantee the combo, though it seems to happen only with maxed Spirit(my observation might be wrong).

How do I trigger that jump slash after the R2+Triangle stab?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to perform the jump, you must have at least one spirit level - so at least white - from completing a spirit combo.

Performing the jump attack will drain one spirit level, bringing it from red to yellow, from yellow to white, or from white to none. Should the jump attack connect with a monster, it will additionally cause the spirit bar to slowly fill over time without the need to hit monsters.

Comment: Ah... so the key is the spirit level and not the gauge